# How to display updated user values?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

<-- Whenever I try to update user info,I am not getting the updated values.But when I reload the page,I get the updated values.Is there a way to get the updated values whenever I hit the update button which is in MiddlePanel? Right now I am fetching all users in loadUsers. -->

```
class Home extends Component {
      state = {
        loadUsers: [],
        currentUser: null,
      };

 

     async componentDidMount() {
    
        const res = await axios.get("http://localhost:5000/users");
        this.setState({ loadUsers: res.data });
      }
    
      setUser = (currentUser) => {
    
        this.setState({ currentUser });
    
      };
    
      render() {
    
        return (
          <Fragment>
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-md-3" style={{ backgroundColor: "#303F9F" }}>
                <Typography variant="h6">List all Counsellors</Typography>
                {this.state.loadUsers.map((user) => {
                  const { _id, firstname, lastname } = user;
                  return (
                    <div key={_id}>
                      <PrimaryButton
                        onClick={(e) => {
                          this.setUser(user);
                        }}
                      >
                        {firstname} {lastname}
                      </PrimaryButton>
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </div>
          <div className="col-md-4">
            {this.state.currentUser  && (
              <div>
                <MiddlePanel user={this.state.currentUser} />
              </div>
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my middlepanel code

```
        const MiddlePanel = ({ user }) => {
        
          const [data, setData] = useState({
        
            firstname: "",
            lastname: "",
            email: "",
            phoneNo: "",
          });
        
          const { firstname, lastname, email, phoneNo } = data;
        
          useEffect(() => {
        
            const fetchUser = async () => {
              const res = await axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/users/${user._id}`);
              setData({
                firstname: res.data.firstname,
                lastname: res.data.lastname,
                email: res.data.email,
                phoneNo: res.data.phoneNo,
              });
      
    
          };
            fetchUser();
          }, [user._id]);
        
          const handleChange = (e) => {
        
            const { name, value } = e.target;
            setData({ ...data, [name]: value });
          };
        
          const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        
            e.preventDefault();
        
            const newUser = { firstname, lastname, email, phoneNo };
            try {
              const config = {
                headers: {
                  "Content-Type": "application/json",
                },
              };
              const body = JSON.stringify(newUser);
              await axios.patch(
                `http://localhost:5000/users/${user._id}`,
                body,
                config
              );
            } catch (err) {
              console.log(err);
            }
          };
        
          return (
        
            <div>
              <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <Input
                  type="text"
                  name="firstname"
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  value={data.firstname}
                />
                <Input
                  type="text"
                  name="lastname"
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  value={data.lastname}
                />
                <Input
                  type="email"
                  name="email"
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  value={data.email}
                />
                <Input
                  type="tel"
                  name="phoneNo"
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  value={data.phoneNo}
                />
                <PrimaryButton>Update</PrimaryButton>
              </Form>
            </div>
          );
        };
```

I want to display the updated user info which I am doing in the Middlepanel

Answer (score 0):

try this code , I tested this in codesandbox it works

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

class Home extends Component {
  state = {
    loadUsers: [],
    currentUser: null
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    const res = await axios.get("https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2");

    this.setState({ loadUsers: res.data.data });
  }

  setUser = (currentUser) => {
    console.log(currentUser);
    
    this.setState({ currentUser });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-3" style={{ backgroundColor: "#303F9F" }}>
            {/* <Typography variant="h6">List all Counsellors</Typography> */}
            {this.state.loadUsers
              ? this.state.loadUsers.map((user) => {
                  const { _id, first_name, lastname } = user;
                  return (
                    <div key={_id}>
                      <button onClick={()=> this.setUser(first_name)}>
                        {first_name} {lastname}
                      </button>
                    </div>
                  );
                })
              : null}
          </div>
          <div className="col-md-4">
            {this.state.currentUser && <div>{this.state.currentUser}</div>}
          </div>
        </div>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```